# malloc preventing garbage from being printed?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

Program was programmed in C and compiled with GCC.

I was trying to help a friend who was trying to use trying to (shallow) copy a value that was passed into a function. His the value was a struct that held primitives and pointers (no arrays or buffers). Unsure of how malloc works, he used it similar to how the following was done:

```
void some_function(int rand_params, SOME_STRUCT_TYPEDEF *ptr){
    SOME_STRUCT_TYPEDEF *cpy;
    cpy = malloc(sizeof(SOME_STRUCT_TYPEDEF));// this line makes a difference?!?!?
    cpy = ptr;// overwrites cpy anyway, right?
    //prints a value in the struct documented to be a char*,
    //sorry couldn't find the documentation right now
}
```

I told him that the malloc shouldn't affect the program, so told him to comment it out. To my surprise, the malloc caused a different output (with some intended strings) from the implementation with the malloc commented out (prints our garbage values). The pointer that's passed into the this function is from some other library function which I don't have documentation for at the moment. The best I can assume it that the pointer was for a value that was actually a buffer (that was on the stack). But I still don't see how the malloc can cause such a difference. Could someone explain how that malloc may cause a difference?

Comment: Based upon that isolated snippet of code you're correct: the `malloc` shouldn't be making a difference. But based upon your description of the problem, there must be something bad going on elsewhere which is affected by this.

Comment: Really need to see more of the function.  `cpy = ptr;` does over write making `cpy = malloc(sizeof(SOME_STRUCT_TYPEDEF));` worthless.  Something else is wrong.

Comment: Really difficult to say without a compilable example that produces the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the evident lack of understanding of pointers is responsible for `ptr` actually pointing to memory that has *not been correctly allocated* (if at all), and you are experiencing *undefined behaviour*.  **The issue is elsewhere in the program**, prior to the call to `some_function`.

As an aside, the correct way to allocate and copy the data is this:

```
SOME_STRUCT_TYPEDEF *cpy = malloc(sizeof(SOME_STRUCT_TYPEDEF));
if (cpy) {
    *cpy = *ptr;

    // Don't forget to clean up later
    free(cpy);
}
```

However, unless the structure is *giant*, it's a bit silly to do it on the heap when you can do it on the stack like this:

```
SOME_STRUCT_TYPEDEF cpy = *ptr;
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip. I'll try to pass it along if I see him soon.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why there difference in the print.
can you show the print code?
anyway the malloc causes memory leak. you're not supposed to allocate memory for 'cpy' because pointer assignment is not shallow-copy, you simply make 'cpy' point to same memory 'ptr' point by storing the address of the start of that memory in 'cpy' (cpy is mostly a 32/64 bit value that store address, in case of malloc, it will store the address of the memory section you allocated)

Comment: Not my code, he was working on something and asked for my help, and i was stumped